# SOAP request to create a Triggered Send (AMPScript, sendable Data Extension, subscriber List)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, triggered-send, subscriber

I'm trying to create a Triggered Send without using the MarketingCloud UI.

The triggered send is using an AMPScript email and a Subscriber List to honor or not certain emails. However this is a Transactional email.

Then there's a sendable Data Extension that keeps all the emails sent.

**The request is:**

```xml
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CustomerKey>any ext key</CustomerKey>
            <Name>any name</Name>
            <Description></Description>
            <Priority>Low</Priority>
            <SubscriberList>
               <CustomerKey>EXTERKEY_SUBSLIST</CustomerKey>
            </SubscriberList>
            <SendClassification>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <!-- Transactional -->
               <CustomerKey>AAAAAAAA-7D34-E411-9E06-BBBBBBBBBBBB</CustomerKey>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            </SendClassification>
            <Email>
               <CategoryID>2134</CategoryID>
               <Name>EMAIL_AMPSCRIPT_NAME</Name>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <!-- My AMPScript email -->
               <CustomerKey>CCCCCCCC-2342-4170-A468-4D2FECBA4678</CustomerKey>
            </Email>
            <!-- -->
            <SendSourceDataExtension>
               <CustomerKey>AAAA5555-0000-1111-2222-AAAAACCCAFAA</CustomerKey>
            </SendSourceDataExtension>
            <TriggeredSendStatus>Active</TriggeredSendStatus>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
```

**And the response I receive is:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:11dbf1cb-528a-47ec-8e74-ced9b5782e55</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:95e9ae8c-ab00-4cf9-8546-cf0efbd5a7d7</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsse:Security><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-4b2af549-d94c-4c27-9a54-f3726c5e7110">
            <wsu:Created>2017-06-16T23:47:42Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2017-06-16T23:52:42Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Results>
            <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>Exception occurred during [CreateTriggeredSendDefinition] ErrorID: 1629461444</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <ErrorCode>2</ErrorCode>
            <NewID>0</NewID>
            <Object xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                <CustomerKey>any ext key</CustomerKey>
                <Name>any name</Name>
                <Description>any desc</Description>
                <SendClassification>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CustomerKey>AAAAAAAA-7D34-E411-9E06-BBBBBBBBBBBB</CustomerKey>
                </SendClassification>
                <TriggeredSendStatus>Active</TriggeredSendStatus>
                <Email>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CustomerKey>CCCCCCCC-2342-4170-A468-4D2FECBA4678</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>EMAIL_AMPSCRIPT_NAME</Name>
                    <CategoryID>2134</CategoryID>
                </Email>
                <Priority>Low</Priority>
                <SendSourceDataExtension>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CustomerKey>AAAA5555-0000-1111-2222-AAAAACCCAFAA</CustomerKey>
                </SendSourceDataExtension>
            </Object>
        </Results>
        <RequestID>cabecdac-300a-4117-5528-214400aabbaa</RequestID>
        <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
    </CreateResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I know from the response that the SubscriberList is not a valid field or is not being defined correctly. I also tried without this SubscriberList field and I got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
    <Object xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition"
    ...
    ....
       <AutoAddSubscribers>true</AutoAddSubscribers>
        <List>
        <!-- This is the Subscriber's list-->
         <CustomerKey>yourCustomeryKey</CustomerKey>
         <ID>number_id</ID>
        </List>
    ....
    ...
    </Object>
```